# Fast way to select the correct face of a cubemap?

Tags: c, assembly, 3d

Given an axis-aligned cubemap centered in the origin and an arbitrary point in 3D space, the straightforward way to check which face the point lies into consists in grabbing the coordinate with the greatest magnitude and selecting the face corresponding to that component.

The naive code would read as follows:

```
if (fabs(point.x) >= fabs(point.y) && fabs(point.x) >= fabs(point.z)) {
    if (point.x >= 0) {face=0;} else {face=1;}
}
if (fabs(point.y) >= fabs(point.x) && fabs(point.y) >= fabs(point.z)) {
    if (point.y >= 0) {face=2;} else {face=3;}
}
if (fabs(point.z) >= fabs(point.x) && fabs(point.z) >= fabs(point.y)) {
    if (point.z >= 0) {face=4;} else {face=5;}
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same thing that is considered to be better in C? 
Would branchless code be more optimal?

Any inline assembly standard of choice can alternatively be used for the purpose.
If necessary, all the `\>=` operators can be turned into `\>` operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might not look like much, but the first three `if` statements eliminate all of the calls to `fabs` as well as replacing the inner `if` statements in the posted code. The final `if/else` takes a maximum of two compares/branches to determine the answer.

```
if ( point.x < 0 ) {
    x = -point.x;
    fx = 1;
} else {
    x = point.x;
    fx = 0;
}

if ( point.y < 0 ) {
    y = -point.y;
    fy = 3;
} else {
    y = point.y;
    fy = 2;
}

if ( point.z < 0 ) {
    z = -point.z;
    fz = 5;
} else {
    z = point.z;
    fz = 4;
}

if ( x >= y ) {
    if ( x >= z ) { face = fx; } else { face = fz; }
} else {
    if ( y >= z ) { face = fy; } else { face = fz; }
}
```

Comment: Nice rewrite +1. I would like to see what other people have to say on the matter before accepting any answers for now tho.